# How to resign keyboard when click wherever on view in iphone using Mono Touch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I need to hide the keyboard wherever I click on the view of any part for iPhone using monotouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try...

```
     - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
     {
          [textFieldName resignFirstResponder];

      }
```

Comment: Could you explain in monotouch?

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean by monotouch?

Comment: Mono touch is a frame work we are implementing the code by using c# language.you are implementing in object c..

Comment: Ok, then I dont know whether it will work for you or not. I am sorry.

Comment: If I will get anything about it, I will surely reply.

Comment: I wrote like this    public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches,UIEvent evt)
  {
   txtAdd1.ResignFirstResponder();
   txtAdd2.ResignFirstResponder();
   txtCardname.ResignFirstResponder();
  }

Comment: If you need to hide the keyboard wherever you click on the view.You need to hide the keyboard for this in which event you will write in your object c..Could you write the code in your own language object c ...

Comment: In objective c we use the above code to dismiss the keyboard. touchesBegan is in built function. and textFieldName is uitextfield.

Comment: But i have scroll view i enabled userinteraction even i can not do this..But i can do by imageview..But problem is i am having scroll view ,that scroll covers full of screen.How can i do it?

Comment: I can not handle with scroll view touch.Have you any idea..For which controls we can use this touch event?

Comment: check the scrollview documentation there should be some way to handle it.

Comment: Sorry,i didn't find solution for touching on scrollview textfield not dissmissing..Could you help me..